# Hibernate updating DB when HttpSession is invalidated

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I have a Struts2 webapp that uses Hibernate to access a MySQL database. When a user logs on, I use Hibernate to retrieve a 'User' and a 'Company' object, each within their own Hibernate session which is closed immediately. These 2 objects are then stored as `HttpSession` variables so they can be used for subsequent actions.

When a user logs out, I call :

```
HttpServletRequest.getSession(false).invalidate();
```

to clean up the users browser/HTTP session. As a result of this call however, I see that Hibernate is UPDATING the User object, but it is not updating the Company object.

Neither of these objects were changed in memory, so why is Hibernate updating it? And why one but not the other?

Answer (score 0):

OK, my bad. I had inherited this code and just found a SessionListener that was doing an update to the User table to effectively log them out. It had looked very strange that calling 'invalidate()' invoked Hibernate... but I guess that's what SessionListeners are for!

Nevermind...